# Oauth token to be used across mutiple scenario and scenario outline file in Karate

Tags: karate

I have created a separate feature file to get the access token and it gets stored in a variable. And then I am trying to use callonce feature  in Background to get the variable value stored to be reused across the feature file containing scenarios and scenario outline for access token. But somehow it always returns null in the response.

token.feature looks like

```
   Given url microsoft
   And path '/f35555555555/oauth2/v2.0/token'
   And header Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  And form field client_id = appClientId
  And form field client_secret = appClientSecret
  And form field grant_type = 'client_credentials'
  And form field scope = appScope
  When method post
  Then status 200
  And def appAccessToken = response.access_token.value
```

And opt.feature file looks file this:

```
Feature: GET-order

  Background:
    * def result = callonce read('OTP/authentication.feature')
    * def token = result.appAccessToken

  Scenario:

    Given url fire
    And path  '/api/fire/v' + version + '/sms/otp'
    And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
    And header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token
```

Comment: sorry, no one can help you with the lack of info, I think it is best if you follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas -  But is this is right way to get the token value or am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: looks correct, but impossible to be sure :)

Comment: @PeterThomas : what more information is needed here. I will add more info  as required.

Comment: there is nothing. as far as I am concerned you have to follow the process in the link. you can certainly choose to wait for someone else here who may have more patience to help

Comment: Ok thank you. @PeterThomas

Comment: The logs would be very helpful. 
And,.. you are calling `OTP/authentication.feature` and you talking about `token.feature` and `opt.feature`. Would be great to clarify that as well.